# Как убрать и заменить элементы из виджета поиска, который сгенерировал WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, как решить 2 вопроса:

1. Как убрать в виджете поиска, которого сгенерил WordPress с надписью Найти
2. Как в input убрать value Поиск и поставить вместо слова иконку поиска font awesome

[image: вид на сайте]

[image: часть кода]

Comment: Все можно сделать через css

Answer (score 0):

Используйте фильтр формы поиска:

```
function get_search_form_filter( $form ) {
    $form = preg_replace( '/<span.+<\/span>/', '', $form );
    $form = str_replace( 'Поиск', '', $form );
    $form = preg_replace( '/<input (.+)>/', '<i class="fas fa-search"><input $1></i>', $form );
    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'get_search_form_filter' );
```